# How to force the user to login when connecting Linkedin Account

Tags: linkedin-api

I want to give the user the ability to add multiple linkedin accounts , the problem is if the user already authorized linkedin to the app, linkedin skip the authorization page and directly redirect back with the token. (the solution for now is to tell the user to logout from linkedin).

But with twitter api, I can add to the authrization url something like this : force_login=true

is there something like this in linkedin ?

Comment: Have you across a option like this?

Comment: No, unfortunately

Comment: I've come into this problem and trying to figure out myself